# Extracting a URL for BBC AAC radio stream from their config file (contents inside)

Tags: streaming, internet-radio

I found some links for BBC radio stations. I'm trying to get the actual url for their AAC stream for BBC5.

They are listed here. http://support.bbc.co.uk/multicast/streams.html

The contents of the file for the BBC5 acc are :

```
v=0
o=bbcrd 1140190509 1140190509 IN IP4 132.185.224.80
s=BBC 5Live Sports Extra [AAC]
i=Multicast trial service from BBC Research & Development Copyright (c) 2006 British Broadcasting Corporation
a=x-qt-text-nam:BBC 5Live Sports Extra [AAC]
a=x-qt-text-aut:BBC Research & Development
a=x-qt-text-cpy:Copyright (c) 2006 British Broadcasting Corporation
u=http://www.bbc.co.uk/multicast/
e=Multicast Support <multicast-tech@bbc.co.uk>
t=0 0
c=IN IP4 233.122.227.170/32
m=audio 5170 RTP/AVP 96
b=AS:128000
a=rtpmap:96 mpeg4-generic/44100/2
a=fmtp:96 profile-level-id=1;mode=AAC-hbr;sizelength=13;indexlength=3;indexdeltalength=3;config=1210
```

But from this I don't have the knowledge to put together the actual URL that is used.

Does this make sense to anybody? Or is the another way to skin this beast?

Comment: Not sure where this should go (webapps?), but I don't think this is the right place for this question.

Comment: It might help to know exactly what your endgame is? Do you want to capture the streams or just make a list?

Comment: My goal is to get a direct URL to the stream so i can play it in my app. Something similar to this direct stream url http://mp3-ar-32.as34763.net:80/

Comment: You might want to try with a different station. Sports broadcasting (BBC Radio 5 Live) is restricted to UK only, so you limit the number of people who can help you. Most other radio broadcasts are available internationally. Give us the BBC Radio 4 or BBC World Service details instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking at is an [Session Description Protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2327) file that basically tells you the IP where the stream is to be found and what it actually is.

So here's the information about where the stream is:

```
c=<network type> <address type> <connection address>    
c=IN IP4 233.122.227.170/32
```

And here for the media stream contained:

```
m=<media> <port> <transport> <fmt list>
m=audio 5170 RTP/AVP 96
```

Now, as far as I'm concerned, you should be able to open a media player like VLC and let it connect to `rtp://233.122.227.170:5170`, which should get you the stream's contents.

However I can't access anything at that URL which is probably due to the fact that BBC limits its broadcasting to UK only IP addresses.